# Large firebase function requests seem to cause connection error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that works perfectly well when I'm running it on my local machine. It sends an email. This is the code:

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const msg = req.query
  return sgMail.send(msg)
    .then(mailResponse => {
      return cors(req, res, () => {
        res.status(200).send(mailResponse)
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return cors(req, res, () => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(200).send(err)
      })
    })
})
```

However, when it is deployed, whether I'm requesting it from my local machine or from my hosted deployment with firebase, I encounter this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at ... from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

However, *if the request is small enough, then it goes through*, fires the function correctly, and produces no error. It's only when I try to push through a relatively large email that has a lot of report data that I encounter this issue.

I tried to switch from a GET to a POST request but this seemed to have no effect.

The firebase functions log says things like `Function execution took 696 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'` when the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) for HTTP functions, you may get errors like that if cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) isn't set up properly.

CORS consists of two requests: a preflight **OPTIONS** request, and a **main** request that follows the OPTIONS request.

The preflight request contains headers indicating method and additional headers, which will be sent in the main request, as well as the origin of the main request.

To handle a preflight request, you must set the appropriate **Access-Control-Allow-*** headers to match the requests you want to accept. Please see this [**link**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#functions_http_cors-tabs) for an example.